# Content alignment in Twenty Fourteen Theme

Tags: css, content, theme-twenty-fourteen

I am fighting around with a quite simple but at the moment not solvable problem.

I set up a WP site on an external server for trying first time WordPress and was successful. Now setting it up on an own internal server I got everything working, just one thing changed:

The content, never mind if page or blog entry is quite far away from the left side bar in twenty fourteen theme.
Not so in the "Trial" installation, any idea?

CSS checked up and down and not found.

Twenty Fourteen theme.
Navigation on the left and the top.
Distance between right border of the left navigation bar to the text starting in the middle is so big.
Text seems centered in the middle area.

So the main content area would be good to have more left aligned.

Thanks!

Comment: More information is necessary.

Comment: Please add additional information to you question by [editing](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/181446/edit). Besides more technical valuable and relevant information would be much better, like code, differences in setup and such.

Comment: code is difficult, style.css it so long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a tool like firebug (http://getfirebug.com/). It will give you the precise values and locations of the applicable css-styles in your style.css. If you use the same file in both installations there should be no differences except for different content or different devices.